# How can I use a nullable Boolean in combination with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use a **nullable boolean** in `Thymeleaf`. If I use a normal boolean (primitive type) everything works fine. But when I use the **Boolean class** I get the following error:

> smokingAllowed is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does
> the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

The code below should give you a clear image of what I'm trying to achieve.

RoomFilter (Spring class)

```
public class RoomFilter {
private RoomType roomType;
private Boolean smokingAllowed;

public RoomType getRoomType() {
    return roomType;
}

public void setRoomType(RoomType roomType) {
    this.roomType = roomType;
}

public Boolean isSmokingAllowed() {
    return smokingAllowed;
}

public void setSmokingAllowed(Boolean smokingAllowed) {
    this.smokingAllowed = smokingAllowed;
}
}
```

HTML (Thymeleaf)

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{smokingAllowed}">
     <option th:value="null" selected>---</option>
     <option th:value="1">Smoking allowed</option>
     <option th:value="0">Smoking not allowed</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Since the Boolean class is not recognised as a boolean by default, you need to have a different naming convention.

When you use a boolean (primitive type) Thymeleaf / Spring is looking for the getter named isNameOfProperty().

When you use a Boolean (class) Thymeleaf / Spring is looking for the getter named getNameOfProperty().

Therefore, the following code worked:

Spring

```
public class RoomFilter {
    private RoomType roomType;
    private Boolean smokingAllowed;

    public RoomType getRoomType() {
        return roomType;
    }

    public void setRoomType(RoomType roomType) {
        this.roomType = roomType;
    }

    public Boolean getSmokingAllowed() {
        return smokingAllowed;
    }

    public void setSmokingAllowed(Boolean smokingAllowed) {
        this.smokingAllowed = smokingAllowed;
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf HTML

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{smokingAllowed}" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option th:value="null" selected>---</option>
    <option th:value="true">Smoking allowed</option>
    <option th:value="false">Smoking not allowed</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is all explained in the Java Bean Specification (https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/). And isn't related to Spring or Thymeleaf but rather how bean introspection in Java works.